# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_version' when importing mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="root", database="Master")

print(conn)

conn.close()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python needs a MySQL driver to access the MySQL database.
install mysql-connector :

```
python -m pip install mysql-connector
```

Start by creating a connection to the database

Use the username and password from your MySQL database:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  passwd="yourpassword"
)

print(mydb)
```

Comment: I have the same problem but in Heroku. I cannot manually install the library. I made the requirements.txt file and ran `pipreqs --force`

Answer (score 0):

I had the myaql connector in place but git the following error:

```
mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    import _version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_version'
```

Neither `pipreqs --force` nor `python -m pip install mysql-connector-python` could resolve the problem. However, the solution by Arpit Jain solve the issue.